# Display foreach statements next to each other in razor C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display blog posts in my razor view right next to each other.

I have managed to display the blog posts but not inline the way i would like to. Instead each post is below each other

**View**

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    <div id="misublog">
        <a href="@post.Id" target="_blank">
            <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => post.Title.Text)</h4>
        </a>
        <small>@Html.DisplayFor(model => post.PublishDate.UtcDateTime)</small>
        <p>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => post.Summary.Text)</p>
        <a href="@post.Id" target="_blank">Read more</a>
    </div>
}
```

**CSS**

```
 .feature {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    margin: 0 0 50px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display:inline-block;
}
#misublog {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Best

Comment: What do you mean by "after each other"? Bear in mind that you've got a paragraph with the summary text in... Additionally, do you *really* have the block indented all the way over to the right? It's making your post very hard to read...

Comment: sorry about that. I have edited it. What i meant to say is the posts display below each other.

Comment: and yes I do have the title, date and summary of the post in a div

Comment: Well, you have multiple `div` elements... wouldn't you *expect* those to display one after another? Perhaps you really want a `span`? I suggest you experiment with plain HTML first - this isn't really a question about MVC or Razor at the moment. If you can work out the HTML you want to produce but then you have difficulty producing it from MVC, *then* it would be a sensible MVC question...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting your code, but since you're new, bear in mind: we are real people here, with real lives. We care enough to try to help other developers, *gratis*, so the least you can do is take the time to write a well thought out question, *with properly formatted code*. If you care so little about your own question, why should we care more?

Comment: sure thing chris.  John Skeet let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements cannot contain block-level elements. While technically, you can put block-level elements in there, the browser will not respect the inline, and assume you must have intended to have a block instead, because there's blocks inside.

Use `display: inline-block` if you want an element that's both inline and contains block-level elements. However, keep in mind that IE7 and below do not support `inline-block`, so if you have to support those browsers (I pity you), it won't work.

However, there is a workaround. The following CSS will trick IE7 and below into treating the element in similar way to `inline-block`:

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

To add that you can use a star-hack, which will only be seen by IE7:

```
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```